# Keyboard macro software

Tags: windows, keyboard, macros

I'm looking for a super-simple free keyboard macro program. Does not need to "automate" anything just send some keystrokes when a key is pressed. Ok, not just letters some arrows and enters.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Actually that was what I meant! (But AutoIT would work too.)

Comment: Yep...I use both. I dig AutoIT.

Answer (score 2):

[AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is free and can do what you want, but not terribly simple. If you don't find anything simpler, you can probably get it to do what you want in under an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) that runs too [in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/custom-keyboard-layout-with-windows-10/b71c7905-1e30-4b0c-861b-253efd2b5a9e)